# How can I call C# custom function in NHibernate grouping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the below code, but NHibernate can't recognize custom C# function.

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<MyObject>().Select(
            Projections.Group<MyObject>(x => GetDateTimeOffset(x.Date)),
            Projections.Sum<MyObject>(x => x.TotalBytes));

public DateTime GetDateTimeOffset(DateTime date)
{
    ..............
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't because there is noway it knows how to translate your function to sql.

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use [Named queries](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/17/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-lt-query-gt-and-lt-sql-query-gt.aspx).